# Serialize list of object to JSon to make finding by key efficient in jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serialization, json.net

Building an API to return a list of translations from a database. The list will have a Key such as HomePage and then the translations value_e = "Home" and value_f = "accueil".

The goal is to then load the list using jquery ajax and for each element on the page which needs text, I would find the correct translation using the key and the current culture.

If I use this physical file,

```
{
    "translations": [{
        "Home": {
            "en": "Home",
            "fr": "Accueil"
        },
        "Product": {
            "en": "Product",
            "fr": "Produit"
        }
    }]
}
```

I am able to use this jquery in order to return the data

```
//data return from ajax call
var t = data.translations;

var pageTitle = t[0].Home[lang];

document.title = pageTitle;
```

I'm attempting to write the correct code to produce this from our database instead but this is the result I get.

```
"{\"translations\":
      [{\"key\":\"Home\",
         \"en\":\"Home\",
         \"fr\":\"Accueil\"},
      {\"key\":\"Product\",
         \"en\":\"Product\",
         \"fr\":\"Produit\"}]
}"
```

My API code

```
public partial class translation
{

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<translation> translations { get; set; }
    }

    public string key { get; set; }
    public string en { get; set; }
    public string fr { get; set; }
    public static string List()
    {
            //Query SharePoint for the data here

            var result = new List<translation>();
            for (int i = 0, len = items.Count; i < len; i++)
            {
                result.Add(CreateTranslation(items[i]));
            }

            var model = new RootObject();
            model.translations = result;

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);            
    }
    public static translation CreateTranslation(ListItem listItem)
    {
        var foo = new translation();

        foo.key = listItem["Key"] == null ? String.Empty : listItem["Key"].ToString();
        foo.en = listItem["Value_e"] == null ? String.Empty : listItem["Value_e"].ToString();
        foo.en = listItem["Value_f"] == null ? String.Empty : listItem["Value_f"].ToString();

        return foo;

    }
```

Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You need one Home class and Product class which are property of translation class.Then In the home and product class you can have two properties like `en and fr`

Comment: I don't know enough to give you a complete answer but it looks like you're having issues serializing the Json. `JsonConvert` creates a string literal, which if that is your return type wouldn't be read properly on the other end if the response Content-Type header isn't application/json.

Comment: Did you grab that JSON string off the wire or did you copy it from the 'locals' or 'watch' window in Visual Studio? Those windows escape double quotes with a backslash. It may be that your string is just fine.

Comment: The resulting json was from chrome

Comment: Is `List()` your web api method?  If so, it should return a `RootObject` not a string.

Comment: @Niladri - I cant make a new class for every possible translation I'll ever have.

Comment: @BrianRogers, thx that helped with the formatting at least

Comment: So I got it working with this, though i'm not sure sure how efficient it is..
`
      function getObjects(obj, key, val) {        var i = getObjects(d, 'key', 'PortalTitle'); // Returns an array of matching objects

        document.title = i[0][lang];
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
      }
`